# MYSQL Group By DateTime Range at specific time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum data by everyday in a month at specific time range. Here is the table :

```
Table data

| amount | created_at          |
| 220    | 2019-08-01 10:50:00 |
| 120    | 2019-08-01 12:00:00 |
| 320    | 2019-08-02 01:00:00 |
| 550    | 2019-08-02 09:30:00 |
| 440    | 2019-08-02 02:00:00 |
```

Here is what I've done so far :

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount, DATE(created_at) AS label
FROM data
WHERE created_at between '2019-08-01 09:00:00' and '2019-09-01 09:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

The result is

```
| total_amount | label |
| 340          | 2019-08-01 |
| 1310         | 2019-08-02 |
```

However I want to range between certain time everyday. Like from 09:00:00 every day in a month. So I got 24 hour per day not from **00:00:00 to 23:59:59** but from **2019-08-01 09:00:00 to 2019-08-02 09:00:00** and so on. So the result should be :

```
| total_amount | label      | description
| 1100         | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-01 09:00:00 to 2019-08-02 09:00:00
| 550          | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02 09:00:00 to 2019-08-03 09:00:00
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: your expected results are wrong. They should be: 1100 and 550

Comment: yes you were right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract 9 hours:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount, DATE(created_at - interval 9 hour) AS label
FROM data
WHERE created_date between '2019-08-01 09:00:00' and '2019-09-01 09:00:00'
GROUP BY label;
```

Comment: Note that referring to aliases in the GROUP BY clause is a MySQL extension.  It is not according to the SQL standard, and this query would be rejected in many other database systems.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to subtract 9 hours from `created_at` and `group by` the result date.
No need for a `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
  t.total_amount,
  t.label,
  concat(t.label, ' 09:00:00 to ', date_add(t.label, interval 1 day), ' 09:00:00') description
from (
  select 
    sum(amount) total_amount, 
    date(date_sub(created_at, interval 9 hour)) label
  from data 
  group by label
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbJ5HqYjPBDPQyGpMVN9kY/1).
Results:

```
| total_amount | label      | description                                |
| ------------ | ---------- | ------------------------------------------ |
| 1100         | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-01 09:00:00 to 2019-08-02 09:00:00 |
| 550          | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02 09:00:00 to 2019-08-03 09:00:00 |
```